# How to detect Media Services are installed on Windows server 2003?

Tags: wix, windows-server-2003

I've been trying to find some information on this.  So far I've been using the version Key presence to do it, is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

What's installed on a box is noted in several places, none of which reports everything, so you'll have to look at each to find where Media services install info is.

WMI classes:

Win32_ApplicationService

Win32_QuickFixEngineering

Win32_SoftwareFeature

Also MsPIDinfo:
 http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/scripting-jscript/t-microsoft-programs-ids-277777.html

And, interestingly, uninstall info in the Registry at subkeys below:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall